# How to use a cart collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to use sessions to track users and also update my cart collection:

```
app.post('/cart/:id',function (req, res)
{
    if(!userKey)
    {
        userKey = req.session.id;
    }

    Cart.findOne({userKey : userKey},function (err, cart)
    {
       if(err)
       {
           console.log("Error finding cart "+err);
       }
        else if(!cart)
       {
           cart = new Cart();
           cart.userKey = userKey;
           cart.items = [];

           cart.save(function (err)
           {
               if(err)
               {
                   console.log("Error saving cart"+err);
               }
                   Ticket.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function (err, ticket)
                   {
                       if(err)
                       {
                           console.log("Error finding ticket "+err);
                       }

                       cart.items.push({
                           type:ticket.type,
                           price:ticket.price,
                           quantity:req.body.quantity,
                           total:ticket.price * req.body.quantity,
                           time:ticket.time,
                           date:ticket.date
                       });

                   });
           });

       }
        else if(cart)
       {
           Ticket.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function (err, ticket)
           {
               if (err)
               {
                   console.log("Error finding ticket " + err);
               }

               cart.items.push({
                       type: ticket.type,
                       price: ticket.price,
                       quantity: req.body.quantity,
                       total: ticket.price * req.body.quantity,
                       time: ticket.time,
                       date: ticket.date
                   });

           });
       }
    });
});
```

Above is my code in my route.js file.I'm building an express and node app.I have a page with items that can be added to a cart and I have a cart collection. The code works for when I am adding the first item to the cart, it checks to see if there is a cart and seeing there is none, it creates a new one, assigns a session id to the userkey variable and inserts the new item.
The problem is when I'm adding extra items to the cart, instead of updating the cart, it overrides the existing data in the cart. I'm not sure how to solve that

Answer (score 0):

I have to save the cart after inserting the item. so i added

```
 cart.save();
```

After the Ticket Insert function